How come my Java gradle project that uses a library is not including the library's dependencies in the consumer project?
Acccording to The Java Library Plugin,
using the api configuration on a dependency of a library with the java-library plugin should put that dependency into the classpath of a consumer of the library. However, that simply just does not work for me. In my consumer project, I use the implementation configuration to include my library, whilst my library has the api configuration to include its dependencies. However, the dependencies are simply not inside of the consumer's shaded jar file that shades in the library. Does anyone know why this is? Do I have to take any additional steps to get this working?
I have tried this so far, to no avail:
Library Project:
    dependencies {
     api("my-library-dependency")
    }

Consumer Project:
    dependencies {
     implementation("my-library")
    }

    tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
    dependencies {
    include(dependency("my-library"))
    }
   }

In the decompiled jar file of my consumer project, I see no trace of the dependency of the library. It is like it is just not included at all. I can get it to work by doing this in my consumer project:
    dependencies {
    include(dependency("my-library"))
    include(dependency("the-dependency-of-my-library-in-the-consumer-project"))
    }
   }

but this is redundant, and I feel as though I should not have to explicitly declare this. If I have multiple dependencies especially, this will end up being messy. It is showing up underneath my library in my runtime classpath in my gradle dependencies, it is just not being shaded in.

Your issue is highly likely to be with how you are using the Shadow Jar plugin, not the native Gradle plugins.

I fixed this by simply removing the dependencies block inside of the shadowJar task. This works because the behaviour of the shade plugin makes it so that it will include everything on the runtime classpath if the dependencies block is not specified. The reason that the dependency is not included when trying to use my library is that the shade plugin would like you to explicitly declare all of your dependencies, and transitive dependencies are not an exception to this. So, the only way I found to fix this is to remove the dependencies block entirely, making it include everything on the runtime classpath. Otherwise, if you would like to customize it further and exclude certain things, I believe that you would have to explicitly declare the dependency.
